# what is the constant field of irreducible components a divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, function-fields

Let $D$ be a divisor on an algebraic variety over a field $k$, that is 
$$
D=\sum n_i D_i 
$$ where $D_i$ are the irreducible components. I came across the expression "the constant field of $D_i$" and I would like to know what does it means. I guess it has to do with the residue field of $\mathcal{O}_{X, \xi}$ where $\xi$ is the generic point of $D_i$, but what is the precise relationship? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A reasonable definition would be: "constant field" =  the algebraic closure of $k$ in the residue field $k(\xi)$ (equal to the function field of $D_i$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, QiL. However, in the context I've seen this expression, $k_i$ is a finite extension of the base field. Is it possible that it means $\Gamma(D_i, \mathcal{O}_{D_i})$?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is projective or more generally proper over $k$. Then the field $\Gamma(D_i, O_{D_i})$ is a finite extension of $k$ contained in $k(\xi)$, thus contained in $k_i$. The equality holds if for instance $D_i$ is a normal variety.